# Org-Mode percentage value

Tags: org-mode, percentage

Is there any way to assign a percentage value to the headings when they are marked as DONE?

```
* HEADING 1 (100%)
** HEADING 1.1 (20% OF TOTAL)
** HEADING 1.1 (50% OF TOTAL)
** HEADING 1.1 (30% OF TOTAL)
```

Default would be 33% each.

Answer (score 3):

You could handle this with [Checkboxes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html):

```
* Cheese [50%]
 * [X] Fancy [100%]
   * [X] Red Leicester
   * [X] Tilsit
   * [X] Caerphilly
   * [X] Bel Paese
   * [X] Red Windsor
 * [-] Extra Fancy [33%]
   * [X] Stilton
   * [X] Gruyère
   * [ ] Emmental
   * [ ] Norwegian Jarlsberg
   * [ ] Liptauer
   * [ ] Lancashire
```

Comment: I´m using TODO keywords and tags. That is why I want to use headlines. What I´m trying to do is to set a custom percent done value to each item. Thanks anyway for your answer ant time.

Comment: Then your best bet is to look at effort estimation.
I think the effort for subheadings is calculated into the effort of their parent.